# What does it mean by seek time and buffer in Harddisk specification?

Tags: hard-drive

In Harddisk Detail specification there are two things called Harddisk seek time and buffer.Will anybody explain it in detail?
Usually seek time is 12ms.What is better lower seek time or higher seek time?

Answer (score 2):

Most of the basic information you need is on wikipedia
[Seek time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_disk_drive_performance_characteristics#Seek_time) - basically the time it takes for a drive to move to a track - the shorter the better - it means you can switch between tracks faster, which means slightly faster random reads/writes.

SCO has a pretty nice image explaining this in their [documentation](http://osr507doc.sco.com/en/PERFORM/disk_IO_mech.html)

[image]

[Buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_buffer) is fast memory used as a form of cache on the drive itself - the more the better. Since hard drives, and (to a smaller extent) SSDs suck compared to ram, this is used for things like temporarily storing data that may not be immediately needed but will be needed later, dealing with the drive being slower than the interface its connected to and other clever things. More buffer generally is a sign of a better drive, but its not something you usually notice immediately on a consumer drive.